# Batch mode learning with the Beta Binomial model

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, machine-learning, bayesian

I am trying to learn about the Beta Binomial for Bayesian style probability. So far I have:

$p(D|\theta)$ is the **likelihood** of the data set.

$D$ is the data set.

$p(\theta)$ is the prior probability of the parameter $h$ (I would use $\theta$ instead of $h$, but for this example I'd rather use discrete probability instead of continuous).

So the **posterior distribution** is **proportional** to the likelihood times the prior:

$p(\theta|D) \propto p(D|\theta) \times p(\theta)$

**My question is this:** suppose we first get a data set $D_1$, and we use it to obtain a posterior distribution. But then (like batch style learning), we obtain another data set $D_2$. **We first calculate the distribution given $D_1$ using the above equation, *but then how do we update $\theta$ before using the equation again to obtain the new posterior from $D_2$?***

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so initial the posterior is $$p(\theta|D_1)=\frac{p(D_1|\theta)p(\theta)}{\int_{\theta\in\Theta}p(D_1|\theta)p(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta},\forall\theta\in\Theta$$ where $\Theta$ is the parameter space.

The old posterior becomes the new prior distribution.  The updated posterior becomes $$p(\theta|D_1;D_2)=\frac{p(D_2|\theta)p(\theta|D_1)}{\int_{\theta\in\Theta}p(D_2|\theta)p(\theta|D_1)\mathrm{d}\theta},\forall\theta\in\Theta$$

Comment: Hello Dave, when you say p(theta | D1 ; D2), you mean p( (theta|D1) | D2), correct?

Comment: One more thing, suppose you wanted to actually modify theta so that the following would be true:  p(new_theta) = p(old_theta | D1) ... how would you change theta?

Comment: As to first comment, no I meant what I wrote.  The probability of theta given both d1 and d2.

Comment: As to second comment.  It is notationally acceptable to drop the "given d1" from the posterior to make it a prior if you wish.   I kept the notation in my answer so you could see the posterior was now a prior.